# Development desk - power solution

Tags: power

I've got a pretty...awkward project, to try to simplify my life with the great many devices being plugged/unplugged, the clutter of cables around my desk, and the general awkwardness of it. The theory is simple: bind as much as possible **into** the desk.

The first step, and possibly the most important one to reduce the crazy number of power cables, would be to try to build the power sockets for various devices into the desk. This is where my dilemma comes in:

1. I'd really like to reduce the size of the power plugs from the UK standard to something preferably smaller. Obviously, I want to keep all three separate pins, and I'd prefer a connector that is as easy as possible to find (as I'll have to strip quite a few plugs bare). The desk will still have the odd UK socket due to devices that come with a wall converter, but I'd ideally like to have as few of those as possible. What kind of connector pair would handle 220V with up to 6A current draw?
2. I'd like to digitally control the supply of power to the said sockets. Arduino programming is not an issue - soldering is not an issue - heck, anything electronics is not an issue. What would be the best solution? Thinking solid state switches but I don't think that this is the best approach for it.
3. Is there anything obvious in terms of safety barring me from possibly doing this?

Any input on any of the three points would be more than appreciated. There are a few other things planned for it (homebrewed KVM) but this should not be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of sockets, for price then you can't beat IECs (kettle leads). They are cheap, but not very secure and might fall out easily. You can also get multi-outlet panels, as seen on the back of UPSs.

If you want something a bit more secure and easy to terminate, have a look at the [powerCON](http://www.neutrik.com/en/lighting/powercon/) from Neutrik. These will take 16/20A and are locking, so very secure. The only issue is cost, with each connector being a few quid each, depending on where you get them from.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer towards powerCON!

I was thinking IECs from the get-go, but I was wondering if there was anything smaller. Seeing as most of the devices around the desk actually use IECs, it'd make the most sense.

Now, to find a way to switch power on/off!

Comment: Just be aware that the 20A powerCON does not have a breaking rating, ie. it should not be disconnected under load. The newer powerCON TRUE1 does have a breaking rating, but I've never actually seen any of them around yet.

Comment: c.cam: I'm not planning to disconnect anything under load. The only possible screw-up as to current suddenly cutting off would be a power cut, which occurs relatively infrequently around Oxfordshire. However, I think I might stick with the IEC leads - it saves me a lot of powerplug re-grafts!